# Access VBA "Path not found" when using MkDir to create folder on desktop

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, mkdir

I'm attempting to create a folder from a form in MS Access. I need to have the ability to create a new folder for each form entry. I'm a novice VBA programmer, but have learned a lot through searching and testing techniques online. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Create_File_Folder_Click()


Engine.SetFocus
    If Dir("C:\Users\ndemos\Documents\Test\" & TimeDateTeam.Value, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir ("C:\Users\ndemos\Documents\Test\" & TimeDateTeam.Value)

Const strParent = "C:\Users\ndemos\Desktop\Test\"
    Dim strTimeDateTeam As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim fso As Object
strStudentID = Me.TimeDateTeam
strFolder = strParent & strStudentID
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
MsgBox "Specified folder already exists.", vbInformation, "File Folder"
    Exit Sub
    
Else

fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If
Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus

End If    
End Sub
```

I am running into a run-time error 76 "path not found" when I try and click the button in my form to create a folder. I've made sure the path actually does exist, and have tried and failed with multiple other directions for the folder to go to (such as \Documents\ and so forth).

Any help with how to create the folder would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `OneDrive` installed? Right click on "Documents" folder -> properties and see what `Location` it show. Is it something like "C:\Users\YourUser" or "C:\Users\YourUser\OneDrive"?

Answer (score 1):

First, "\Test" must exist. Then this will work:

```vb
Path = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Test\" & Me!TimeDateTeam.Value
If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir Path
End If
```

Comment: Yes, it will work in any circumstances, but if you have OneDrive installed, starting from this moment you will have two "Documents" folders. One in your user profile (keeping only the "Test" folder) and the system one with the path "C:\Users\YourUser\OneDrive\Documents"...

Comment: @FaneDuru: That, I think, will depend on how (or if) you sync the Documents folder to OneDrive.

Comment: Yes, it is so. As default, if you do not change it, "Documents" folder is included in the synced list. At least, this happened in my case. I use a function ("OneDriveExists") when need to set the path to such a folder. If installed, `Environ$("ONEDRIVE")` will return its path.

Comment: Thank you! Environ$("ONEDRIVE") did the trick. If I wanted to add an MsgBox for if the folder name already exists, how would I go about that? I've tried a couple different techniques, but have mostly returned errors. I think there should be a simple "If - else" solution, but I just can't quite put my finger on it.